# Is there a "Open terminal here" from File Browser?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Something equivalent to Windows' "cmd prompt here", that will open a gnome-terminal on a specific folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a nautilus (gnome's file manager) extension for that:

http://packages.debian.org/sid/nautilus-open-terminal

That is the package for debian. You should look in the repository of your distribution for a similar package.

Comment: As described in the documentation, after installing this package you must reload nautilus by running `killall -HUP nautilus` or by logging out.

Comment: When I installed this in CentOS 6.5 `yum install nautilus-open-terminal` I have there two options - "Open in Terminal" and "Open in Midnight Commander" (mc was installed before) - amazing!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Nautilus as your 'File Browser', it is as simple as a few entries in `nautilus-actions`  GUI...  Any 'actions' you create are available via a right-click of the mouse, and also via the Nautilus Toolbar if you wish (and I think also via the menu).

- ..Command: gnome-terminal
- Parameters: --window --maximize --working-directory=%d
- and a couple of other equally easy options.

You can get Nautilus Actions* via the command: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions`

When you have installed it, run `nautilus-actions-config-tool`  (to get started)

... and you can use Nautilus for **much** more than just this script...

Comment: Using nautilus-actions allows for the option to be used not only on folders but also on files (meaning "open a terminal on the folder where this file is").

Answer (score 4):

In the absense of an installed extension, you can drag the icon for a folder to Gnome Terminal or Konsole and it will expand to the single quoted path.  First type `cd` followed by a space, then drag the icon over and press enter.  And naturally, you can use this with other commands like mv, cp, etc.  I think Konsole might actually pop-up with a menu asking whether you want just the path or the full cd command saving some typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the add-on for it, you can just go up a level in File Browser so you can see the folder, right-click it, and choose "Open in Terminal". This works for me on Nautilus 3.26 in RHEL 7.6.

You can check if you have the add-on by opening Application Installer, searching for Nautilus, and scrolling down to the Add-ons section. It's called "Terminal plugin for Files".